# How to STOP flash/blink taskbar icon in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Referencing this question:
[How to flash/blink taskbar icon in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565087/how-to-flash-blink-taskbar-icon-in-vb-net/67011493#67011493)

I am aiming to do the opposite and stop the taskbar icon from flashing.

My big attempt has been to override OnNotifyMessage

```vb
      Protected Overrides Sub OnNotifyMessage(m As Message)
            'MyBase.OnNotifyMessage(m)
      End Sub
```

This however seems to mess with my placement of the forms, seems to prevent processing of Top Left commands from executing.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? When is the *blinking* happening? Why do you need to *stop it*? I.e., a better description of the context wouldn't hurt -- BTW, OnNotifyMessage must be enabled, using `SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true)` in a Form and you don't even need to call `base`, it's just a notification. -- If it's about the first time the app is run, see the notes here: [Window not activated when the application is run from Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394232/7444103)

Comment: When moving between forms, and one gets activated it flashes the toolbar icon for the deactivated form.  It's annoying and distracting is the reason it needs to stop because it's meaningless for the app it happens in.

Comment: When you switch between Windows with normal means (`ALT+TAB`, mouse click etc), the taskbar icon doesn't flash, it's just highlighted. So it's something you're doing. You need to described the context in which this happens and how you're switching between different Windows, so the effect can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Still, no solution to this particular problem but my workaround was to hide the toolbar icon and create a tray icon instead.  Not the ideal solution but at least don't have to see that annoying blinking every time, I activate or deactivate an app.